# Tomcat in Docker with webapp: Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: javascript, java, docker, websocket, java-websocket

I have a Java webapp and a browser application that connects to it over WebSockets like this in my client-side Javascript code:

```
function connect() {
    var username = 'my-user';

    var url = `ws://${document.location.host}${document.location.pathname}chat/${username}`;
    log(`making WebSocket connection to ${url}`)

    var ws = new WebSocket(url);

    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        log(message.message);
    };

    ws.onerror = (event) => {
        log(event);
    }
}
```

The endpoint when running Tomcat locally is `ws://localhost:8080/my-app/chat/my-user`

The endpoint when running Tomcat under Docker is `ws://localhost:8090/my-app/chat/my-user` (port 8090)

This works fine when connecting to my local Tomcat, but not when connecting to Docker Tomcat.

The error I get back when trying to connect to the Docker Tomcat is:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8090/my-app/chat/my-user' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Any ideas?  From what I can tell, I don't need to open any additional ports in Docker (I have 8090 mapped properly).  I don't know if there is any additional logging I can turn on in Tomcat to show me the endpoints.  Maybe I just am not specifying the right endpoint?

Comment: Can you provide the docker command you are using to start your docker container?

Comment: Essentially, anytime your application boots up in development mode it want to keep an active connection to the development server and be notified anytime some file changes. This does happen when working with Docker. It sounds like you have not set up your Docker Tomcat to allow websocket connections.